# Correct way to compare file paths when one is canonical and other absolute

Tags: java, android, path

In my testing, I find `myfile.getCanonicalPath()` produces paths such as:

```
/data/data/<pkg>/files/...
```

and `myfile.getAbsolutePath()` produces paths such as:

```
/data/user/0/<pkg>/files/...
```

Given a method such as:

```
public boolean pathsAreEqual(String p1, String p2) {
  // return true if both paths represent the same location in filesystem
}
```

or

```
public String getRelativePath(String p1, String p2) {
  // return a reduced p2 to a relative path from p1

  // was hoping to use Path.relativize() here but that fails due to prefix diffs.
}
```

the leading path difference is problematic.

The only approach I can think of is to traverse the paths (right-to-left) until the pkg name is found and use that as the root.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: First: return true if both paths are the same. Second: replace "/data/data/"  by "/data/user/0/". Third: return true if both paths are the same.

Comment: So which prefix can I count on for *any* device - i.e. it's not clear which is implementation dependent.  The "second" approach seems fragile not knowing what devices may produce.

Comment: Thise three will do.

Comment: Why would you want to treat these paths as identical? They point to different files, don't they? Are symlinks involved?